# Stop Highchart when end of the Array element reached

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

So What I am trying to Create is a Chart in which around 130 points data are flowing in a single second time. Now, Suppose I Have an array of 1000 elements which I want to render in Highchart.

I am able to render the Highchart with the 1000 elements of array, but the problem is that after the end of the array, the Highchart is not stopping. it keeps running.

I just want to stop the Highchart when it reaches end of the array.

Here is the Code that I have tried

```
 var data = [7,10,8,6,8,2,5,2,2,2,3,4,4,10,6,10,5,10,0,2,9,5,7,0,5,0,5,7,8,7,5,1,9,1,5,7,10,3,7,0,2,10,8,8,1,1,0,7,6,3,1,10,0,8,3,5,5,10,3,8,4,0,3,5,8,7,0,0,0,8,7,3,2,1,0,6,7,7,3,7,5,0,1,0,0,4,9,4,4,3,0,2,10,9,0,2,7,6,5,9,0,6,7,9,0,6,2,7,1,6,5,1,3,1,0,5,0,4,2,7,2,0,7,0,3,10,6,3,4,9,9,10,10,9,5,9,8,5,3,2,5,9,5,10,10,7,8,3,8,9,5,3,9,0,1,2,6,4,1,9,0,5,0,5,6,4,1,1,3,8,2,0,7,6,4,0,6,5,5,6,4,6,6,3,3,5,5,8,7,3,4,7,5,6,1,4,2,4,7,9,8,4,0,3,8,6,2,6,10,8,10,1,10,8,6,8,8,3,8,7,8,6,7,10,9,10,0,7,7,8,1,10,1,4,7,10,7,0,9,6,3,3,3,1,4,3,4,5,0,5,9,0,6,1,8,5,1,8,9,4,0,4,5,4,3,8,2,10,5,9,4,9,5,3,6,5,7,2,2,7,1,1,9,7,4,1,7,5,2,10,6,4,3,5,7,2,4,5,7,3,2,0,8,5,5,7,8,2,9,5,9,1,2,0,7,8,10,5,6,9,2,5,1,9,4,0,7,4,4,7,10,0,8,6,0,6,4,4,8,3,9,1,3,0,0,4,4,2,5,3,3,6,1,4,6,6,4,9,7,0,2,2,1,2,2,6,2,0,2,5,7,8,8,1,7,3,9,0,0,0,9,4,9,8,9,7,10,8,2,0,5,10,10,0,1,7,5,9,2,8,10,10,4,6,6,6,10,10,5,1,5,2,1,9,3,2,5,3,1,3,10,7,1,3,5,3,0,6,7,5,1,10,5,9,0,9,2,3,0,10,0,6,9,8,3,8,7,0,10,4,2,2,5,6,7,0,10,10,9,9,8,6,10,5,9,0,6,4,8,5,0,4,4,4,1,8,3,0,9,3,3,9,1,5,0,10,1,1,3,10,6,5,8,0,6,5,2,7,10,4,2,0,10,1,7,6,2,0,1,6,10,10,6,6,10,1,4,7,5,6,5,4,1,5,6,9,1,8,4,7,2,8,5,9,7,3,9,2,2,8,10,6,10,10,7,8,7,2,6,8,7,4,6,1,5,9,2,0,5,4,4,0,4,5,7,2,3,8,9,1,0,8,6,10,8,3,7,3,3,6,7,2,7,6,6,2,8,6,9,6,8,5,4,8,4,6,7,9,8,7,8,5,8,2,0,8,5,0,5,2,8,4,7,0,7,1,4,8,10,8,2,5,10,9,1,9,3,0,6,9,2,10,5,1,4,0,4,9,1,1,3,5,0,5,5,2,5,1,1,7,0,2,6,8,10,7,9,3,0,9,4,2,4,6,2,2,9,2,7,3,6,6,9,2,2,0,2,9,1,5,7,10,10,1,8,5,9,9,4,1,7,1,0,0,6,7,7,7,2,9,9,2,10,5,4,2,3,10,9,9,7,1,1,6,8,4,9,6,7,4,9,4,2,7,6,2,6,0,1,5,5,8,9,5,1,7,8,7,3,2,3,1,1,2,5,6,4,10,8,10,3,3,1,0,6,7,0,7,4,8,4,7,6,0,7,1,2,3,10,4,1,10,7,9,4,7,7,10,10,10,6,8,9,7,3,10,9,0,3,6,2,10,5,3,6,8,5,0,2,3,1,6,9,10,9,10,7,5,8,7,4,4,3,10,2,3,4,3,10,8,5,9,8,5,6,2,4,9,1,5,0,7,1,1,4,4,10,4,7,8,8,9,7,1,9,5,5,4,3,0,0,9,5,6,3,3,4,6,1,2,6,2,8,4,10,0,9,1,10,2,7,3,6,3,9,2,3,5,7,8,1,1,9,3,4,6,7,6,2,2,8,0,10,3,3,5,7,4,1,3,9,5,4,3,3,2,9,8,7,8,7,6,8,7,7,1,2,10,10,2,9,3,2,3,2,9,9,0,3,0,4,9,6,0,1,6,9,5,8,7,9,5,6,8,3,5,3,4,9,8,0,3,4,8,6,9,4,7,1,9,8,0,4,8,1,0,7,3,3,1,6,9,9,5,4,3,8,8,9,10,4,9,0,7,8,6,9,8,4,10,4,1,2,5,4,0,6,4,1];


        var json_array = data ;

        var i = 0;
function next() {  

  return json_array[i++];
 // i++;
}
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0],
                    chart = this;
                var count = 0 ;
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y =next();
                        console.log(y) ;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
                    chart.redraw(false);
                }, 1000/130);

            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'ECG Graph Plot From MySQl Data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        //max: 1.5,
        //min: -1.5,
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        animation: false,
        name: 'ECG Graph Plot From MySQl Data',
         dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    },
        data: (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -1000 ; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 10,
                    null
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

I Have also created a Fiddle for it as you can see below.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/toqaxLj7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear Interval when it reached the last element of the array. check out following code.

```js
var draw = setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y =next();
                        console.log(y) ;
                         if (i == data.length) {
                            clearInterval(draw);
                            return;
                        }
                       
                    series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
                    chart.redraw(false);
                }, 1000/130);
```

here is the fiddle code link.
https://jsfiddle.net/geekcode/8nL53x01/1/